# TFS Object Model 2017 TeamProjectPicker not working with VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've been using TeamProjectPicker with different version of TFS Object Model, but since Visual Studio/Team Explorer 2017. It's not working with VSTS specially when using Azure Active Directory account to connect with VSTS. For on-prem TFS with on-prem active directory accounts it works fine.

If I would use TFS Object Model 2015 it works fine and connect to VSTS without any problem. I'm working on a product/application which picks the installed version of Visual Studio and uses the Object Model of the same VS/TE by using dependency injection. Means if I install my application on machine having Visual Studio/Team Explorer 2015, my application will start using TFS Object Model 2015.

```
var tfsPp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false);
DialogResult dialogResult = tfsPp.ShowDialog();
```

[image]

If there's limitation of TeamProjectPicker (TFS OM 2017) with VSTS, I'm ready to change the dialog window. I've been looking VS Services Client Lbrary but could find any dialog window. If I can have connection dialog window that's shown in Team Explorer that would be acceptable.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you need some impersonation here.

Comment: Can you share the entire code?

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's permission issue, just as Mike mentioned you may need some impersonation here.

Based on the error messages you can refer below articles to troubleshoot them:

- [TF31003: Your user account does not have permission to connect to
  the Team Foundation Server {0}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/error/tf31003-user-account-no-permission-connect-tfs?view=vsts)
- [How To Fix TF30063 Error - You Are Not Authorized To Access Team
  Foundation Service Error](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-tf30063-error-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-team-foundation-serv/)
- [TFS API Part 29 – TFS Impersonation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104019/TFS-API-Part-TFS-Impersonation)

---

**UPDATE:**

Just try to install the Nuget Package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for your project.

I tested on my side, everything works as expected with the VS 2017 installed only.

[image]

Comment: Then why does it work with Team Explorer (TFS Object Model) 2015's libraries.

Comment: @arsalanyounus Yeah, I mean it's against the TFS OM 2017. Are there any differences when you using the libraries between 2015 and 2017? Have you checked this issue on other machines?

Comment: No, There is no difference.

Comment: @arsalanyounus Can you connect to VSTS directly from Visual Studio 2017? I tested on my side, everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes it is connecting from from Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @arsalanyounus Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No the issue still exists, please inform if you have any solution for it?